# y value of candle doesn't match the real axis value

Tags: delphi, teechart

When I draw 2d candle stick series with the following simple code the Y value of open/close is 0 but it doesn't match the 0 of the axis. The former is 1 or 2 pixel higher than the latter(the grid of the axis).

```
Series1.AddCandle(0, 0, 1, -1, 0);
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug I added to the defect list (TV52016642) to be investigated. For High and Low points you have two options:

1- Changing axis offset:

```
  Chart1.Axes.Left.MinimumOffset:=-1;
  Chart1.Axes.Left.MaximumOffset:=-1;
```

2- Changing axes minimum and maximum:

```
  Chart1.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(Series1.MinYValue, Series1.MaxYValue);
```

Comment: thanks but they don't work. the open/close of the candle follows the movement of the offsets. you can find this problem through the sample which is 'open close style' in teechart pro examples.

Comment: @user2575398 setting the chart to 3D, Stick or Bar style and setting the offsets works there for me. Does this works fine at your end?

Comment: i can't recognize the problem in 3d mode but i need to use 2d mode. when the axis moves by the adjustment of the offsets the candle moves along together. i attached the source files to the following linked webpage. thanks. [link](http://blog.naver.com/lotusforge/40193087511)

Comment: @user2575398 sorry, I meant it works fine for me in 2D. Which TeeChart version are you using? Your project works fine for me here with latest 2013.08.130521.

Comment: i use the same version of you. please check the following image which you tested sample project. thanks. [image](http://blog.naver.com/lotusforge/40193098612)

Comment: @user2575398 thanks for the image. I misunderstood your problem. I could reproduce it and I think it's a bug. I have added it (TV52016642) to the defect list to be investigated. I updated my reply accordingly.

Comment: when there are many candles and the candles are small the problem is getting worse. thanks a lot.